# Why the Observer in NSNotification called twice....?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, notifications

If the class is a custom class, after posting the notification, the selector corresponding to the observer is called twice.. Is there any better solution so that the selector is called only once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the observer class is registered for a notification by name, but not against a specific object, it will receive multiple messages, as it will be invoked every time the notification occurs, regardless of the originating object.

Likewise, if the observer is registered against a specific object, but not against a named notification, it will be messaged every time there is a notification concerning that object.

An alternative mechanism for being informed of changes in a distant state, is Key Value observing -http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html

Answer (score 7):

If the selector is called twice, you've probably registered for it twice.

Comment: The problem is, There are two controls in the nib, which is customized to the same Class. and Since the observer is been registered in the awakeFromNib() of that Class, the selector is also called twice for a single postNotification. :(

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was a couple of things:

1-In the class where the addObserver registration call is made, was to add a specific object.

2-In the class where the postNotification call is made, as the same type of object.

I also do my postNotificaiton in a dispatchAsync call as well, but that's not related to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the addObserver is set only once. In my case, the addObserver loop ran twice, hence the bug.